# Mount an FTP as a drive letter in Windows 7

Tags: gratis, windows-7, ftp

I am looking for a free program that can mount an FTP server as a drive letter in Microsoft Windows 7.

What I have found so far:

- [WebDrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/): works great, but non-gratis
- [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/): works great, but non-gratis
- [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/): works great, but non-gratis
- [FTP Drive](http://www.killprog.com/fdrve.html): gratis, but the last version was released in 2006

Comment: Haven't tested it,  so I won't put it as an answer,  but what about http://www.ferrobackup.com/map-ftp-as-disk.html?

Comment: "FTP Drive: gratis, but the last version was released in 2006" - does it still work?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider [Eldos' SFTP Net Drive](http://sftpnetdrive.com/), it works very well and if you're ok with just a single drive you can use it free of charge. The only thing that you may not like is that it doesn't support the FTP protocol, you will have to use an SFTP (SSH) server with it.

Answer (score 1):

As hhaslam11 commented [FtpUse](https://www.ferrobackup.com/map-ftp-as-disk.html) is freeware solution, I've tested it on Windows 10. It uses [Dokan](https://dokan-dev.github.io/#) filesystem core.
I have some codepage issues, but for most people it is not problem.